# How to resolve GC overload limit exceeded in scala code

Tags: java, scala, solr

I m just reading the record from solr node. my code is doing only reading the records within given daterange. I have checked, it is working for 50K records but I tryied for 100k, then getting GC overload limit exceeded found.

my code is something like this in scala:

```
def querySolr(core: String, selectQuery: String, server: SolrClient,
            pageNum: Int, pageStart: Int, pageSize: Int): (Long, SolrDocumentList) = {
    val query = new SolrQuery(core)
    query.setQuery(selectQuery)
    query.setStart(pageStart)
    query.setRows(pageSize)
    val response: QueryResponse = server.query(query)
    val results: SolrDocumentList = response.getResults
    val total = results.getNumFound
    (total, results)
  }

  def pageCalc(page: Int, pageSize: Int, totalItems: Long): (Int, Long, Long) = {
     val from = ((page - 1) * pageSize) + 1
     val to = totalItems min (from + pageSize - 1)
     val totalPages = (totalItems / pageSize) + (if (totalItems % pageSize > 0) 1 else 0)
     (from, to, totalPages)
  }

 def getRecordsFromSolr(core: String, solrhost: String, userName: String, password: String,
                     query: String): List[SolrDocument] = {

     val startTime = System.nanoTime()
     val url = "https://" + solrhost + ":8983/solr/" + core
     val solrPort = 8983

     val builder: SSLContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder()
     builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
     val sslsf: SSLConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
      builder.build(),  SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
)

   val credsProvider: CredentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(solrhost, solrPort),
   new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password))

   val httpclient: CloseableHttpClient =HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build()

  val server: SolrClient = new HttpSolrClient(url, httpclient)

   logger.info("solr connection completed")

   val pageSize = 1000
   var pageNum = 1
   var nextPage: (Int, Long, Long) = (0, 1000, 0)
   var offset: Long = 0

   var totalResult = querySolr(core, query, server, pageNum, 0, pageSize)
   var total = totalResult._1
   var results: List[SolrDocument] = totalResult._2.toList
  while (total > offset) {
    offset += pageSize
    pageNum += 1
    nextPage = pageCalc(pageNum, pageSize, total)
    totalResult = querySolr(core, query, server, pageNum, nextPage._1, pageSize)
    total = totalResult._1
    results = (results ++ totalResult._2.toList)
 }
 }
```

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

How to avoid the memory leak. I tried with 8GB per core. and table contains milion of records.

I found following error for 60K records:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 0:0 was 18311053 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (10485760 bytes) - reserved (204800 bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically OutOfMemoryError errors appear when reading solr responses which are too large.

Therefore a solution is to minimize the solr response:

1. limit the rowsize
2. limit the returned field list (parameter fl). Especially fields which contain large indexed documents (such as pdfs) could be grow to large sizes.

It this does not help I would recommend to analyze your solr response.
Try to find out the actual solr query and execute it in the browser.